# How do I find the borrower names who have different addresses but are on the same Account No.?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have included some sample data below. The table name is Borrower_TBL

| Borrower No. | Account No. | Borrower Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 567 | John O'Brien | Rogers Park, Chicago |
| 2 | 567 | Mary O'Brien | Rogers Park, Chicago |
| 1 | 294 | Killian Dempsey | Balreask , New York |
| 2 | 294 | Bernie Dempsey | 25 Supple Park, San Francisco |
| 1 | 916 | Colm Logan | The Downs , Dublin |
| 2 | 916 | Tom Logan | The Downs , Dublin |
| 3 | 916 | Gary Logan | The Downs , Dublin |

I need rows 3 & 4 returned as they are both on account 294 but have different addresses. The table is essentially partitioned on Account No. with Borrower No. as the row number.
It should involve a CASE WHEN statement capturing where the text string is not equal in the Address field, I am not sure exactly how to go about this.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Why do you need a `CASE` *expression*? Doesn't seem like anything other that a `COUNT` a derived table/CTE is needed.

Comment: window function?

Comment: Is it necessary to use CASE WHEN?

Comment: Maybe `SELECT DISTINCT a.[Account No.], a.[Borrower No.], a.[Borrower Name], a.[Address]
FROM Borrower_TBL a
JOIN Borrower_TBL b ON a.[Account No.] = b.[Account No.] AND a.[Address] <> b.[Address]
ORDER BY a.[Account No.], a.[Borrower No.];`